# What is "ECLIPSE SDK"?

Tags: eclipse, sdk, ide

I assumed "Eclipse SDK" was installed by default with Eclipse, I am using eclipse JEE. But when I go try to intall via the update site, I have to option to install it, meaning it is not installed already. Can someone please help me to figure this out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse SDK is the plug-ins for the core of Eclipse and includes the source code plug-ins. You probably already have the normal plug-ins but not the source code.

With the source code plug-ins installed it is easy to read the Eclipse source. Open the Preferences and go to 'Plug-in Development' Checking the 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search' will make the source code available in dialogs such as 'Navigate > Open Type'.

In newer releases of Eclipse the option is called 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java workspace scope'.

Comment: But whenever I install it, and I go back to the update site, it shows me as an option to install again, why is that ?

Comment: Do you have 'Hide items that are already installed' checked on the Install New Software dialog? If you don't you are always shown everything.

Comment: Yes I have it ! what is the problem ?, I can install all over again many times !

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea. This works as expected for me.