# How to view a source code of Eclipse Java SDK examples

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I would like to learn more about "Address Book" example from Eclipse SDK examples source package.
I have installed Eclipse SDK examples source from The Eclipse Project Updates - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.13 via Eclipse/Help/Install New Software.
I can see/run examples from SWT Example Luncher but I have no idea how to find/view the source code.
[image: Eclipse image]

Could anyone help me and advice on how to find examples source code, please?

Comment: Probably the same way you look at any other Eclipse source - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37948567/2670892)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find the source code you can go to the following address

[Eclipse examples](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.13-201909161045/org.eclipse.sdk.examples.source-4.13.zip)

Download the zip file and open it.

Navigate to following location

plugins\org.eclipse.swt.examples.source_3.106.600.v20190626-0450.jar\org\eclipse\swt\examples\

You will then find all the SWT examples sources you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your way works, but I have found only a few examples there,it looks that the address book is not included. Anyway, thanks for helping, I got a different SWT address book example from here: [link](https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.swt.examples/src/org/eclipse/swt/examples/addressbook/AddressBook.java.shtml).